# scipy.optimize.root returning NaN on nonlinear function

Tags: python, scipy

I am using `scipy.optimize.root (scipy v. 0.19.0)` on a nonlinear function.

My code looks something like this:

```
def invalid(num):
    if isnan(num) or num < 0 or num > some_other_number:
        return True
    return False

def target_func(guesses, args):
    for i in range(len(guesses)):
        if invalid(guesses[i]):
            return [float('inf')] * len(guesses)
    # do some other calculations
    return [res(guess) for guess in guesses]

result = root(target_func, guesses, args, method='lm')
```

Most of the time `root` returns the correct result. 
But in one instance, the function returns `NaN`, meaning that the "optimal" solution had a target function of inf. In this case, the solver had previously tested a valid guess and received a result that was definitely less than infinity. But once it receives an inf result, it seems to go crazy and won't go back to finite numbers.

Is there something I should be doing differently to solve this problem? Thanks!

Update: I discovered a bug in my code that was causing the target function to return inf. However, I would still appreciate any input regarding the best way to approach this type of problem.

Comment: What are `new_num` and `some_other_number` in `invalid`? Please provide also the nonlinear function and everything else needed to reproduce the issue; otherwise it is hard to help.

Comment: `new_num` was a mistake which I fixed. `some_other_number` is calculated at a different point in the code. The function is a complex financial calculation which I cannot share due to client confidentiality issues. I hope you will be able to provide some help regardless.

Comment: Difficult to help without a reproducible example. What happens if you replace `float('inf')` by a high number e.g. `10**20`?